# Select, copy or cut the current line in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

In Netbeans I find keyboard shortcuts that deal with the current line of code very helpful, like:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> : duplicate
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> : move
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> : delete

Is there a shortcut for selecting, cutting or copying the current line of code? I've looked through many cheat sheets and thought I'll ask here before attempting a macro.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Cutting current line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
Selecting + copying current line:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
Yes, this actually works, but only when no current selection is active

Comment: +1 this works and is a great shortcut. Not sure why someone -1'd it.

Comment: Also shift + delete will cut the current line

Answer (score 12):

I found you could easily assign a keyboard shortcut for selecting the current line in the Keymap section of the Netbeans Options. I've now mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to do this.

Answer (score 10):

NetBeans supports editor macros.

- Open a document.
- Click in it to set an initial cursor position.
- Click "`Edit > Start Macro Recording`".
- Press <kbd>Home</kbd>, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
- Click "`Edit > Stop Macro Recording`".
- You will now be prompted to name your macro. Use something obvious like `select-entire-line`.
- Click `OK`
- Click `Set Shortcut...` to assign a shortcut to the macro.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using

Comment: exacly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 9):

In Netbeans 7.3, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> to duplicate the current line (the Up/Down determines where your cursor will be after the duplication).  This is shown under the Source menu.

Answer (score 7):

Select any line endpoint and then just press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>
together to duplicate the line.

Answer (score 5):

Triple click anywhere on that line. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I was specifically looking for a keyboard shortcut though. Don't like my mouse so much when coding.

Comment: This is a global shortcurst no specific to Netbeans. You can use it on many applicatio *(Word, Excel, Sublime Text, Thunderbird, etc.)*

Answer (score 4):

alt + shift + arrow key (left or right, depending where your cursor is)

Comment: that's for highlighting additional words one block at a time - a faster way of the standard word processor shortcut shift + arrow key (left or right). It's not what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the case for Windows or Linux, but for example in the latest Netbeans IDE on Mac (v8.0) there is no default binding of the 'Select Line' shortcut. You have to manually specify it in Preferences -> Keymap -> Select Line.

The default binding for 'Delete Line', however, is ⌘-E (Command-E).

(I know this question is old and already answered, but just in case any other Mac Netbeans users come looking for the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

heh he.  I've always used home, shift-end, ^C, since it works in just about every editor there is.

Comment: Thank you! but on my current keyboard layout the Home and End keys are Fn-Home and Fn-End. This translates to 7 complicated key presses on my system. Not exactly a SHORT cut.

Comment: I've remapped a couple keys on my keyboard for the sake of sanity.  (I'm a frequent vi user, so I've remapped capslock to be escape, in place of the crappy calculator-button-style escape key I have on my keyboard.)  You could do a little poking around to find out what the keycodes for the Fn-Etc keys are and map them to proper home and end keys.

Comment: if the original poster is coding in netbeans, he would probably know how to use copy and paste universal shortcuts... unproductive!

Answer (score 0):

On **Netbeans 8.2**, you can use

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> : Shortcut "Copy"
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> : Shortcut "Paste formated"

This will Copy/Paste the complete current line.